# Proplems with formatting DateTime in foreach

Tags: php

I have this code here and it worked fine until I tried formatting dates.

```
<?php foreach ($CLT as $Arr2) : ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $Arr2['VPNummer'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo utf8_encode ($Arr2['VPVorname']) ?> <?php echo utf8_encode ($Arr2['VPName']) ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $Arr2['Firma'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $Arr2['Vorname'] ?> <?php echo $Arr2['Name'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $Arr2['PLZ'] ?> <?php echo $Arr2['Ort'] ?></td>
            <td><?php Dateformat ($Arr2['Datum']); ?></td>
            <td><em class="fa fa-user-edit fa-fw text-muted"></em> <em class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-fw text-muted"></em></td>
          </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I try to format the dates from Database for example 2020-03-12 11:11:12 -> to 12.03.2020
I am using this external function, because that is often needed in different files and tables.

```
function Dateformat($datum)
{
  $newdate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i:s', $datum)->format('d.m.Y');
  echo $newdate;
  }
```

It works for the first entry, then it breaks off. 
I also tried to unset $newdate, but no effect.

```
$CLT = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `InteressentenEmpfehlungen` WHERE `VPID` = 776 AND `Geloescht` = 0 ORDER BY `Datum` DESC");
```

I am using this SQL Statement, perhaps its better to convert the dates before creating an array...

Comment: If you're only using the date for output, then you can use the MySQL [DATE_FORMAT() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to remove a step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have 24 hours time then it will throw an error. use capital `H` in the format.

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $datum)->format('d.m.Y');
```

Comment: I don't understand? The purpose of the formatting is to make the format from 2020-03-12 11:11:12 to 12.03.2020 (also to remove the time, which unfortunately is already in the database). Maybe you can explain to me more exactly what you mean.

Comment: if the incoming date-time string contains times that look like `17:45:13` then the lower-case `h` in the format will treat them as invalid, so your `createFromFormat` won't work; if the time is in the incoming data string, then you need to specify it correctly in the input format, even if you don't intend to use the time in the output format.

Comment: Okay, it was that simple! THANK you, that works fine for me...